# How to make size of button in the LineEdit smaller?

Tags: qt, qlineedit, qaction, qicon, qtoolbutton

I made the X button in the LineEdit, when i click on this button, the LineEdit is clear. But with my method, the X button looks a little big and not beautiful, I need to make it smaller. How I can do it?

[image]

```
myLineEdit = new LineEdit;
myLineEdit->setFixedHeight( 25 );
m_clear = m_lineEdit->addAction( QIcon( ":/clearButton" ), QLineEdit::TrailingPosition );
```

the size of clearButton.png is 12x12 px, so in this case it is enlarged and looks not beautiful like this.

Comment: the solution would be to modify the image so that the x has less size while maintaining the same size of the image.

Comment: @eyllanesc: thank you, I thought about that already. But don't we have solution with coding? Because what happen if in the future I set `myLineEdit->setFixedHeight( 50 );`  then I have to change the size of the image again? Therefore I think the solution with coding would be better :)

Comment: The solution that I proposed can be implemented in code, or without it.

Comment: What size do you want the icon to have? Do you want it to be the same height as the text or a bit smaller? If it is smaller, how much smaller?

Comment: The height of LineEdit is 25 so I want the height of the icon as original size (15*15) :)

Comment: if the height of the QLineEdit is "H", what would be the size of the icon you want.

Comment: I think H*0,7 should be ok as an example

Comment: see my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this solution it is assumed that in the original image the relationship between the foreground size and the background is 1: 1 (this is normal in the icons), so the solution is to increase that relationship, for this we create a new image

```
QPixmap in(":/clearButton");
QPixmap out(in.size()*10/7);
QRect r= in.rect();
r.moveCenter(out.rect().center());
out.fill(Qt::transparent);

QPainter painter(&out);
painter.drawPixmap(r , in);
painter.end();

QLineEdit *m_lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
m_lineEdit->setFixedHeight(25);
m_lineEdit->addAction(QIcon(out), QLineEdit::TrailingPosition);
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]